# Is there a historical basis to this movie's claim about Pope Sylvester II?

Tags: dont-be-afraid-of-the-dark

In the movie [*Don't Be Afraid of the Dark*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_Be_Afraid_of_the_Dark_%282011_film%29) (2010), it is claimed by a character that the creatures

> who, despite never being mentioned by name in the movie, are clearly tooth fairies

made a pact with [Pope Sylvester II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pope_Sylvester_II) to leave humanity alone in return for the right to take a human life whenever they surface. Movie makers usually wildly exaggerate, misinterpret history and mistake myth for history, but rarely insert purely arbitrary historical claims into their movies.

So is there some sort of historical basis, however mythical, for this claim about Pope Sylvester II?

Comment: Shouldn't this be on Skeptics.SE?

Comment: Or History.SE for that matter

Comment: What makes this off-topic but http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9101/ (and maybe http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/11187) on-topic?

Comment: @JoeWreschnig - I think its the idea that the questions are about the language and writing where this is about the historical basis of a fictional plotline.  Do you really think there is a historical basis for a religious head making a pact with fairytalesce creatures to leave humanity alone so long as then only take a single human life?  Do you think that is a resonable question for SE?  I dont unless the author said it was based off of actual events.

Comment: @Chad: "Do you really think there is a historical basis for a religious head making a pact with fairytalesce creatures to leave humanity alone so long as then only take a single human life?" That's the fundamental Christian myth, which has a lot of historical anchorpoints. So yeah, I think there could really be a historical basis for it on a much smaller scale. That doesn't mean I think it _actually happened_, but certainly _someone speaking in earnest could have said it actually happened_.

Comment: @JoeWreschnig I have to agree. If this yardstick is applied uniformly, http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9101/ should be closed too.

Comment: @Pearsonartphoto Hold on a second: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/faq#questions states: "Historical or societal context of a work" is on topic.

Answer (score 8):

A brief Googling revealed nothing closely matching that legend. But on more general ground, Wiki states:

> Pope Sylvester II (or Silvester II) (c. 946 – 12 May 1003), born Gerbert d'Aurillac, was a prolific scholar, teacher, and Pope. He endorsed and promoted study of Arab/Greco-Roman arithmetic, mathematics, and astronomy, reintroducing to Europe the abacus and armillary sphere, which had been lost to Europe since the end of the Greco-Roman era. He was the first French Pope, reigning from 999 until his death.
>
> Due to his efforts to root out simony and other corruption within the Church, and his connection with science and intellectualism, **there were many rumors and legends spread of Sylvester II being a sorcerer in league with the devil.**